# Troublehsooting QGIS Time Manager in OSX

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-2, timemanager

Though it worked with a sample .shp layer with 10 points that I fabricated, the plugin isn't working with the larger data set I am trying to use now (a couple thousand points). It correctly identifies the start date, which leads me to believe that there is no issue with the date data. Then again, every point is visible from the start and all the way through the timeline, which rather defeats the purpose of animation.

Thanks for any suggestions on what to do differently / how to fix this

Comment: You need to provide either the data or more details about the data. Did you specify appropriate time step sizes?

Comment: The data set out as year-month-day, formatted as a string, beginning in 1990 and going through 2011. The data is from UT's Strauss Center [link] (https://www.strausscenter.org/scad.html), though I had to reformat the dates in excel and save as a Windows .csv file. There is an "event" point nearly every day, and I set the time step to a variety of day, month, and week combinations with no visible change.

Comment: Check the layer properties | General | Feature subset query. Does the query look correct compared to the time and step size configured in Time Manager?

Comment: Promising lead, what is supposed to be in the feature subset query? It is currently blank...

Comment: Oh, are you using the CSV directly? Please note the limitations stated on the project website: "It is not possible to time-manage Delimited Text layers. This is a limitation of the data provider. " https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager

Comment: I re-saved the imported .csv as a .shp, does that not overcome that particular difficulty?

Comment: For reasons beyond my understanding, deleting a column called "Loc. Type" has made everything work as it should. Thanks for your help, and thanks for developing such a useful plugin!

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note are the limitations stated on the project website, e.g. "It is not possible to time-manage Delimited Text layers. This is a limitation of the data provider. " https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager

If you use Shapefiles instead, be aware that attribute names should only contain characters and numbers and must not start with a number.